# Implicit Differentiation

Tags: calculus

If $$y=(12s^4-4s^3+12s^2)/4s$$ then 
$$\frac{dy}{ds}
=9s^2-2s+3$$
 but its a multiple choice question that says  $9s^2-2s+3$ for all $s$ or another choice that says  $9s^2-2s+3$ for all $s$ that do not equal 0.

What is the difference I am confused.

Comment: Can you please fix your post, the information in the brackets doesn't make sense. Did you mean $12s^{4} - 4s^{3} + 12s^{2}$? Also, please use latex for all your math information.

Comment: Fixed it, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't implicit differentiation.

The original expression equals $3s^3 - s^2 + 3s$ if $s \not= 0$ and is undefined otherwise because the fraction has the form "$\frac 00$". Thus the derivative is $9s^2 - 2s + 3$ if $s \not= 0$ and is undefined otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$y=\frac{12s^4-4s^3+12s^2}{4s}=3s^3-s^2+3s$$
In the original definition of $y$, $s$ cannot be zero because division by zero is undefined. Although we're able to simplify $y$ and essentially remove the discontinuity at $s=0$, the domain of $y$ still does not include zero because we must consider the original definition of $y$. So now
$$\frac{d}{ds}[y]=\frac{d}{ds}\left[3s^3-s^2+3s\right]$$
$$= 3\frac{d}{ds}\left[s^3\right]-\frac{d}{ds}\left[s^2\right]+3\frac{d}{ds}\left[s\right] $$
$$= 3\left(3s^2\right)-2s+3(1)$$
$$=9s^2-2s+3, \mbox{for all s}\not =0$$